# Is there a maximum limit of the number of users returns by WP_User_Query?

Tags: limit, wp-user-query

I’m working on a search form which filters the users . Everything works but the result is always limited to 299 users.

Here is my code which is vers basic :

```
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'ID', 
        'meta_query' => $query_array,
    );

$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

If i add `'number' => 999999,`

```
$args = array(
        'number'    => 999999,
        'orderby' => 'ID', 
        'meta_query' => $query_array,
    );
```

It doesn’t work, i’m still limited to 299

If i had `'number' => 150,`

It works, the number of result is limited to 150.

I don’t see anything related to this limit in the codex :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Maybe, the issue is not directly related to WP_User_Query but i need to be sure that there is not a limit established by WP_User_Query.

Comment: Use 'number' => -1 to query all users.

Comment: there is _no_ limit and the default is to query all users.  I suspect some plugin is hooking into either [pre_get_users](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_users/) or [pre_user_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/) and setting `$args['number']`.  To find out, deactivate all plugins and see if you get _all_ users.   If so, then reactivate them 1 at a time until you no longer do and you'll know which plugin is doing it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can install the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin and check it's [Hooks](https://ps.w.org/query-monitor/assets/screenshot-5.png?rev=879529) output to see what is hooking into either of those.

Comment: I’ve already tried `'number' => -1` and it is still limited to 299. I’ll deactivate all plugins and hook.